# TYPO3 TCA: Add CSS class selection to inputLink

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm trying to add a CSS class selection in a TCA inputLink Field. I was able to create the selection in the RTE Editor and now I want to be able to select the same CSS classes in TCA link input fields.

Here is my current code:

```
'link' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'foo label',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'renderType' => 'inputLink',
        'size' => 50,
        'max' => 1024,
        'eval' => 'trim',
        'fieldControl' => [
            'linkPopup' => [
                'options' => [
                    'title' => 'foo title',
                    'class' => [
                        'valuePicker' => [
                            'mode' => 'blank',
                            'items' => [
                                ['button', 'Button Style'],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],

            ],
        ],
        'softref' => 'typolink',
    ],
],
```

I couldn't find anything in the [TCA Docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Link/Index.html). I thought I would give it a try with the LinkPopup --> options --> class. But (as expected) nothing happens.

How am I able to define such a selection dropdown in the link input field?

I'm using TYPO3 LTS 11.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have configured, what you are describing...

A *valuePicker* can be placed next to an input field of RenderTypes default, colorpicker, inputLink (-> [TCAref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Properties/ValuePicker.html#valuepicker)). The *class* field in the linkPopup is a simple (hardcoded) form field without a defined renderType or other TCA configuration ([Code insight](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/recordlist/Classes/Controller/AbstractLinkBrowserController.php#L520)).

There are only a few options for configuring a linkpopup (-> [TCAref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Properties/LinkPopup.html#linkpopup)):

- pid
- allowedExtensions
- blindLinkFields
- blindLinkOptions

Setting a prefilled (not selectable) class seems to be possible via `TCAMAIN.linkHandler`-options (-> [LinkBrowser-API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/LinkBrowser/Index.html)). I found an [example](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues/445#issuecomment-313453117) in an issue of EXT:bootstrap_package.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Thats what I guessed, thats it's not possible to create a selectable class within the linkPopup